# Async run event loop until condition is met in Python

Tags: python, asynchronous

I'm new to Async and, I wanna create a script that will execute a request every half second to check if a website is available. So even if the website response time is like '4s' it will execute another request every 0.5 seconds. Once one of the requests receives the "200" status code the event loop will break.

```
URL = "https://stackoverflow.com"


async def load(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.status == 200

async def create_session():
    complete = False
    while not complete:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            task = await asyncio.create_task(load(session, URL))
            if task:
               break
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(create_session())
```

Right now I got something like this which obviously won't work.

Comment: What means `won't work.`? Don't expect that we will run it to see what is the problem. Besides it may work correctly on our computers. You have to describe it - in question, no t in comment - and more people will see it. And if you get error then you should show full error message (Traceback) as text (not image)

Comment: Well like this the script is synchronous, I want it be be async to make a request every 0.5 s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to create the desired program using the `asyncio.Event()`.

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp


url = "https://www.somesite.com"


async def load(session, url, flag):
     async with session.get(url) as response:
         if await response.status == 200: #Check if the site is available.
             flag.set() # Flag is set


async def create_session():
    flag = asyncio.Event()
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session: # Create aiohttp Session
        while 1:
            asyncio.create_task(load(session, url, flag))
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5) # Wait 0.5 s between the requests
            if flag.is_set():# If flag is set then break the loop
                break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(create_session())
```